# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo - android.view.InflateException - android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: java, android-studio

I got those errors and i do not now what to do with them:

```
Process: com.example.padmw, PID: 13784
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.padmw/com.example.padmw.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.padmw-O16Jmvxggn14uujqjpCoBw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.padmw-O16Jmvxggn14uujqjpCoBw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
```

What should I do?

XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please tell me if you need anymore info.

Comment: Please show some codes including your xml file, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I worked by replacing

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

With

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```